# How to reload or call some function initState() in flutter while using pop

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am trying to run some method when user click back or I use `Navigator.pop()` in second screen.

I have two screens.

1. Setting screen
2. Edit screen

After editing I pop user to first second. Now in first screen I use `SharedPreference`. But I need to re run a method when user comes back to 1st screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While navigating to `Edit` screen from `Settings` screen, use this (inside your `Settings` screen)

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/editScreen").then((_) {
  // you have come back to your Settings screen 
  yourSharedPreferenceCode();
});
```

---

If you only want to run this code on some event that happened on your `Edit` screen, you can make use of `pop` method inside `Edit` screen like

```
Navigator.pop(context, true); // pass true value
```

And above code should be:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/editScreen").then((value) {
  if (value) // if true and you have come back to your Settings screen 
    yourSharedPreferenceCode();
});
```

---

**Edit:**

`async-await` would look something like:

```
bool value = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/editScreen");
if (value) // if true and you have come back to your Settings screen 
  yourSharedPreferenceCode();
```

Comment: How would the code with `async` and `await` look like?